# How to connect to new WiFi network using adb without rebooting the phone

Tags: android, automated-tests, adb, android-wifi, wpa

I have added network entry into the wpa_supplicant.conf and copied the file to /data/misc/wifi folder in my android device.

adb push wpa_supplicant.conf /data/misc/wifi/wpa_supplicant.conf

After this I toggle WiFi "off" and "on" but my phone only connects to saved network and it overrides the entries in wpa_supplicant.conf.

If I "forget"  the saved network, the device doesn't connect to any network.

Is there any way to force my device to connect to a new WiFi network (without manual intervention) without rebooting the device? My intent is to automate WiFi testing of android device.

Comment: I assume you have a rooted device? Anyways, I'm not sure the data directory is meant to be writable

Comment: I have rooted device  and I can write to data directory.

Comment: Sure, you can write to it, but as you've discovered, the file is being restored from some other location

Comment: If I change the entry in wpa_supplicant.conf and reboot the device then it's able to connect to the network provided in wpa_supplicant.conf file. But I don't want to reboot the phone.